# Replacing two 16.5V transformers with one

Tags: voltage, transformer

I'm an enthusiast so please be gentle! I have a transformer question and can't find a similar previously asked question.

I have an ADT/Honeywell security/smoke system. We experienced a utility generated power surge which burned up at least 7 transformers and caps in the house including HVAC, doorbell, freezer, oven AND the ADT security system transformers, Models XF-1620 and 1321. The 1620 outputs 16.5V/20VA and the 1321 outputs 16.5V/25VA/. I want to replace with one transformer outputting 16.5V/45VA. I think it is just that simple. Am I missing something? I am NOW in the hunt for a whole-house surge protector strategy as well.

Comment: Welcome to EE SE, your logic on replacing two transformer with one, is right, however, I am quite surprised to hear that the transformer failed, this is a part that is rather rugged, and it is quite unlikely for it to burn. Could it be that you have not confused a power supply for a transformer? Anyway, if that is the case, your logic still works; just replace two power supplies for one.

Comment: Since this is for a security system, I'd ask ADT to make the necessary repairs, rather than modifying thing myself - that way, ADT is responsible if the system doesn't work correctly.  There are quire likely other problems besides these transformers.

Comment: @Elmesito - Above a certain voltage, the core will saturate and then only winding resistance will limit the primary current.  A surge of sufficient magnitude and duration will overheat a transformer.

Comment: Thanks again.. its a "plug-in transformer". Input and output are both AC. The spike lasted well over a second. This was not a nano or millisecond event. I saw lights cycling. I called ADT and they will not touch it unless I pay for a monitoring contract with them. Fwiw, they will not even look at it for time/material cost. Most of the other repairs involved replacing PCBs with power supply and/or transformer failures. It seems the spike cooked any power transformation component and protected downstream components. All downstream fuses are intact in all appliance that had them, so far.

Answer (score 1):

### Focus on commercial, off-the-shelf

The idea of a single transformer is fine, just get large enough as you plan.  However I would dissuade you from acquiring one out of an electronics supply, because they are not UL listed as mains electrical equipment.

Appropriate equipment these days will typically screw into a junction box knockout, or mount on the lid of a junction box.  It is sold either at electrical supply houses or heating/cooling supply.  Amazon is a fine source as long as you watch out for "sold by Joe Blow and ships from Amazon" types, make sure they are selling reputable UL-listed items and not the usual Chinese garbage off Alibaba. With mains power, don't fool around.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks.. I'm thinking ELK TRG1640 AC Transformer. Their specs say "UL Listed". Just sent them some email to tray and clarify.

Comment: @p.conway That's fine, the classic "Wall Wart" is an acceptable way to mount a transformer of that type, if you have an appropriate receptacle handy (i.e. classic dual-oval style with the mounting hole in the middle). I'm not familiar with the vendor.